# Discord bot: Respond "Unknown command" when using an incorrectly spelled command

Tags: discord.js

I want to have my discord.js bot respond

> Unknown command, use c!help for available commands" when doing something like, c!hep (misspelled), or a different type of command not implemented, like, c!youtube, or just flat out random letters like c!rgoiw.

Basically just a response if their message doesn't match any commands available.

I don't have any specific code, I'm just using the `const PREFIX = 'c!';` with `let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")` and setting all the commands in a `switch(args[0]){` block.

I don't know really anything about coding, all that i've done so far is pretty self explanatory once wrote out, but I don't know what to go for when writing it from scratch.

Haven't seen any threads online about an unknown command response so I'm assuming it might be impossible to do.
Thanks

```
const PREFIX = 'c!';

bot.on('message', message=>{

let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

switch(args[0]){
        case 'example':
        break;
//Code to respond to the prefix with no matching case
  }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

> A default clause; if provided, this clause is executed if the value of expression doesn't match any of the case clauses.

Example:

```
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
    console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
    break;
  case 'Mangoes':
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound.');
    // expected output: "Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound."
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Sorry, we are out of ' + expr + '.');
}
```

As shown above, if nothing matches (to translate to your use case - if no command is recognized) then execute commands found under `default`

In other words, your code should be

```
switch(args[0]){
        case 'example':
        break;
        default: console.log(`Unknown command, use c!help for available  commands`);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. That seemed really simple so I feel dumb for not knowing but I appreciate it!

Comment: If the Answer helped you press the Green Tick next to it, it will mark your Question as resolved and the answer as the accepted one.