# How to make unknown command prompt in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to have my discord.js bot respond

Unknown command, use !help for available commands" when doing something like, !hep (misspelled), or a different type of command not implemented, like, !lol, or just flat out random letters like !jajaja.

Basically just a response if their message doesn't match any commands available.

```
const prefix = '&'

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return
let [command, ...args] = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g)

switch(command) {
    case "help": 
           // help code here
    break;
    case "test": 
          message.channel.send('test')
    break;
    default:
          message.channel.send(`run ${prefix}help to get a list of commands`)
    break;
}
```

Here is the code I have created. Only issue is that it is doing it for every command, I want it to only do it for the commands that are not available.

I have looked at other posts, but either they give me errors, or give me duplications. Also, lots of post are similar to my issue, it is doing it for every command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.JS Unknown Command not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097897/discord-js-unknown-command-not-working-correctly)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097897/discord-js-unknown-command-not-working-correctly

Comment: That has errors. That doesn’t help.

Comment: That other forum is similar to mine, but they do not have a complete answer. I need assistance.

Comment: Try removing the last break statement after default.